# using HAVING to select only multiple records for specific field

Tags: mysql

```
SELECT  db.people.first_name, 
 db.people.last_name, 
 db.people.email

FROM db.convert,  db.people 
HAVING COUNT(db.convert.year) > 1
WHERE db.convert.email =  db.people.email   
AND (SUBSTRING(db.convert.gross, 1, 2) != '$-')
GROUP BY db.people.email
```

This query works fine without the HAVING statement, but I need it to only select emails that are in the table with multiple records for different years. So 2011, 2012, 2013

Also I want it to show that email and last name only once, distinct?

When I add the having statement the query does not run

Comment: Shouldn't the HAVING go after group or does it not matter?

Comment: awesome the query works now, no more errors.

Comment: Glad it works, I had to refresh myself on having quickly.  You don't need to use count(*) like I suggested your way works, just have to put the HAVING after the GROUP BY.  I added an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HAVING is based on a GROUP BY condition.  So it needs to be after the GROUP BY.

```
GROUP BY db.people.email HAVING COUNT(db.convert.year) > 1
```

As Ollie Jones and Gordon Linoff suggested, if you have more than one record per year for each person then you will want to use a DISTINCT on the COUNT so you aren't counting each year more than once:

```
GROUP BY db.people.email HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT db.convert.year) > 1
```

Comment: The OP may want `COUNT(DISTINCT db.convert.year) > 1` to meet the requirement, the way I read it.

Comment: @OllieJones Yes, good point, this query assumes that db.convert.year is a unique column.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a better way to write this query:

```
SELECT p.first_name, p.last_name, p.email
FROM db.convert c join
     db.people p
     on c.email = p.email
WHERE c.gross not like '$-%'
GROUP BY p.email 
HAVING COUNT(c.year) > 1;
```

In addition to fixing the syntax problem with `having`, I also:

- Introduce table aliases (`c` and `p`) to make the query more readable.
- Use proper join syntax rather than implicit joins in the `where` clause.
- Use `like` rather than `substring()`, so the comparison could take advantage of an index.

Also, `COUNT(c.year)` probably doesn't do what you want.  It is probably the same as `COUNT(c.gross)`, `COUNT(c.email)`, and `COUNT(*), because it counts the number of non-NULL values in`year`.  I'm not sure what you want, but if you want emails with at least two years of records, then the expression should be:

```
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT c.year) > 1
```

Comment: Nice additions.  The aliases and 'not like' I agree with but is there anything particularly wrong with an implicit join or is your point just to organize it for the user so they know where the join is?

Comment: @Devon . . . Let's just say that most people who use SQL agree that implicit joins are very bad style.  They are supported by every database, they are officially part of the ANSI standard, but they are hard to maintain, less expressive (no support for outer joins), more difficult to read, and more prone to errors.

Comment: This is exactly what I needed and you forethought my need for DISTINCT as well. As I wanted to select multiple different years.

Comment: would using JOIN make the query more "reliable" on different interfaces? I am using a proprietary command line tool and the implicit join is giving the wrong results. But they both work correctly (same results) on Putty. Thanks again.

Comment: @alex_b . . . The implicit join and equivalent inner join should give the same results.  If you are observing different behavior, you might want to ask a question here or on dba.stackexchange.com.

Answer (score 0):

You have two requirements, it seems.  (I assume an email uniquely identifies a person.)

One, give a list of persons' names and emails.

Two, show the persons who appear in more than one distinct year in your `convert` table.

The second requirement can be met by this query. It counts distinct conversion years by email and throws out those with only one conversion year. As somebody mentioned in comments, `HAVING` should come after `GROUP BY`.

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT year) AS years, email
  FROM db.convert
 WHERE SUBSTRING(gross, 1, 2) !- '$-'
 GROUP BY email
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT year) > 1
```

Then we can use that as a subquery (a virtual table) to go get peoples' names, as follows:

```
SELECT p.first_name,
       p.last_name, 
       p.email
  FROM db.people AS p
  JOIN (
        SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT year), email
          FROM db.convert
         WHERE SUBSTRING(gross, 1, 2) !- '$-'
         GROUP BY email
        HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT year) > 1
       ) AS years ON p.email = years.email
 ORDER BY p.last_name, p.first_name, p.email
```

This uses the *structured* part of *structured query language* precisely to specify what you need from your tables.

Building up your query this way lets you debug things progressively. You have to be careful when using `COUNT()` or other aggregate functions in table joins, because you may get a lot more rows than you bargained for due to the combinatorial way joins work.